# Delete a Dynamically Created Popover in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular and I have been able to create a bootstrap popover around selected text with the following function

```
 $scope.highlight = function () {

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('tabindex', "0");
        a.setAttribute('data-toggle','popover');
        a.setAttribute("id","1");
        a.setAttribute('data-content',"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='deleteLabel()'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></small></button>");
        a.setAttribute('data-html','True');

        if (window.getSelection) {
                var sel = window.getSelection()
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                range.surroundContents(a);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
        }

        $timeout(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        }, 50);
    };
```

And, in the above code, I create the popover with a button inside it which when clicked (`ng-click='deleteLabel()'`) should call the following function which should delete the element

```
 $scope.deleteLabel= function(){
            alert("removing label");
            var labelEl=document.getElementById("1");
            labelEl.remove();
        };
```

However, it does not appear that `deleteLabel()` is even being called when the button in the popover is clicked. Is there something wrong with how I am calling this function from within the popover?

Comment: Because you can't insert html that contains directives without using `$compile`. Get rid of bootstrap.js and switch to angular-ui-bootstrap. You are already heading down the wrong angular learning path using your own dom manipulation...especially in controllers where none of it should exist

Comment: @charlietfl can you say where `$compile` should be used.  Should I include `$compile(a)($scope)` somewhere?

Comment: Even if you do you are putting into attribute....then plugin will move it and plugin won't compile it. This is just all wrong. You should start over using proper angular methodology

Comment: @charlietfl so `$compile` should not be used in this case?

Comment: It won't do any good because it's not going into the DOM it's going into an attribute that will be extracted later by code you don't control. Angulr doesn't work that way. Start over and use directives

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more Angular way to do so using ngBootbox; please see the [working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XFHdPDINv6xhj5020O6q). In general, you want to avoid DOM manipulation the way people do it in jQuery; this is one of the strength of Angular is to hide that "complexity" from you and the use of directives like ngBootbox is the way to go. If there is a jQuery library you want to use, look for an Angular wrapper.

If I understand your requirements correctly, I have two pop-ups... one to add elements and one to confirm the deletion of elements.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngBootbox']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ngBootbox', function($scope, $ngBootbox) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.name = 'World';
  vm.categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2'];

  vm.prompt = function() {

    $ngBootbox.prompt('Enter a new category?')
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log('Prompt returned: ' + result);
        vm.categories.push(result);
      }, function() {
        console.log('Prompt dismissed!');
      });

  }

  vm.delete = function(index) {
    console.log('delete index=' + index + ' v=' + vm.categories[index]);
    $ngBootbox.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + vm.categories[index] + ' ?')
      .then(function(result) {
        // Remove element
        vm.categories.splice(index, 1);
      }, function() {
        // Do nothing
        console.log('Prompt dismissed!');
      });
  }
}]);
```

To add I call a prompt where one can enter a category and once confirmed I add it to the array of categories and it is automatically added to the page.

The delete one uses the $index of ng-repeat to know which element to delete and if the user confirms the deletion, I remove it from the array using splice and the page is automatically updated thanks to Angular binding.

and the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Hello {{vm.name}} !</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in vm.categories">{{c}} <a href="" ng-click="vm.delete($index)">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" ng-click="vm.prompt()">Add Category</a> 
</body>
```

[ngBootbox](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox)
AngularJS wrapper for Bootbox.js. Bootbox.js allowes you to easily make use of Twitter Bootstrap modals for javascript alerts, confirms and prompts. ngBootbox includes three directives, one for each of alert, confirm and prompt.

[Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) is a small JavaScript library which allows you to create programmatic dialog boxes using Bootstrap modals, without having to worry about creating, managing or removing any of the required DOM elements or JS event handlers. Here’s the simplest possible example:

Also, as you are new to angular, I used the controller as syntax and vm=this to avoid $scope issues; here is an article: [AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Comment: I don't see how this relates to my problem.  It looks like you are adding and removing elements from an array.  I have to add and remove popovers from selected text

Comment: @user1893354 Sorry, I misunderstood your "add and remove popovers from selected text" ; can you show your HTML that calls highlight so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just call it from a button using `ng-click="highlight()"`.  The selected text comes from `window.getSelection()`

Comment: okay.. I have an example where once the text is selected it automatically opens a pop-up asking to delete the selected text:. Is it closer to what you are looking for? https://plnkr.co/edit/VJQE2nKhfGxqzUpoNhAo?p=preview

Comment: What you want is the person selects some text, it creates a link around it, and if the person clicks on that newly created link, it calls a delete function ; correct?

Comment: Its link with a popover (see my js code in the post) around the selected text.  Then there is a button in the popover that when clicked should delete the link/popover.

Comment: ok. I am posting another answer... hopefully closer to what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way of doing. You should do DOM manipulation via [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or use libraries like [bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

In your implementation the DOM element created via createElement is not getting binded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working plunker using the popover.](http://plnkr.co/edit/55jk1NK9VSPBW07DHVZT?p=preview) The user select part of the text and click highlight... then a link is created using your code and it calls the delete function when one presses the delete button. After creating the element, I call to make the ng-click works:

```
  $compile(a)($scope);
```

I display the content and mark the div with 'mycontent' as the id used to delete the selected text:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p id='mycontent'>{{ vm.content }}</p>
  <button ng-click="vm.highlight()">Highlight</button>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    <div class="popover-content">
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>{{link.title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button ng-click='vm.delete()'>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>
```

My app is based on your code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.window = window;

  vm.content = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum';

  vm.delete = function() {
    console.log('delete' + vm.selectedText);
    var d = document.getElementById('mycontent');

    var olddiv = document.getElementById('todelete');

    d.removeChild(olddiv);
  };

  vm.highlight = function() {

    var a = document.createElement("a");

    a.setAttribute('id', 'todelete');
    a.setAttribute('uib-popover', '');
    a.setAttribute('popover-trigger', 'click');
    a.setAttribute('popover-placement', 'top');
    a.setAttribute('ng-click', "info()");
    a.setAttribute('data-html', 'True');
    a.setAttribute('data-content', 'Some content');
    a.setAttribute('uib-popover-template', "'tpl.html'");


    $compile(a)($scope);

    if (window.getSelection) {
      var sel = window.getSelection()
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      vm.selectedText = text;
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      range.surroundContents(a);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }

  };

  vm.getSelectionText = function() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  };

});
```